# Validating existing key values in array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a small form where I enter values (id's and names) and store them in array by clicking a button, but I want to validate if there's an existing id key value in this array because I don't want to add repeated id key values.

Currently I have this:

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="idperson"><input type="text" id="name">
    <button id="add" type="button">ADD</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var people = [];

    $("#add").click(function(){
        var iduser = $("#idperson").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();

        if(people["idperson"]!=iduser){
            people.push({idperson:iduser,nameperson:name});
        }
        console.log(people);
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working because it continues storing repeated idperson values when I enter info in the form:

[image]

I'm sorry if I'm forgetting something, I'm newbie on this.

How can I fix it? I'd like some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `people` is an array of object which contain `idperson` attribute, not the object itself.

This should do the trick :

```
var people = [];

$("#add").click(function(){
  var iduser = $("#idperson").val();
  var name = $("#name").val();

  if (!people.find(person => person.idperson === iduser)) {
    people.push({ idperson:iduser, nameperson:name });
  }

  console.log(people);
});
```

Comment: I forgot to say I had to change `if` line closing parenthesis `iduser))`

Comment: My bad ... Edited

Comment: I have a question, what about if I want to remove element of array who has same iduser, how would be line code?

Comment: Remove the if block and change it for:
people = people.filter(person => person.id !== iduser);

Comment: Ok, but in this case, how can I use `splice` in this kind of array?

Comment: Ok, now I solved it `for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
      if (people[i].usid && people[i].usid === iduser) { 
          people.splice(i, 1);
          break;
      }`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the input data is exist in the people array or not exist.
Check here the working code.

Thanks

```js
var people = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    

    $("#add").click(function(){
        var iduser = $("#idperson").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();

        if(checkPersion({idperson:iduser,nameperson:name}) && people["idperson"]!=iduser){
            people.push({idperson:iduser,nameperson:name});
        } else {
         console.log('User exist');
        }
        console.log(people);
       
    });
    function checkPersion(obj){
  for(var i=0;i<people.length ;i++){
         if(people[i].idperson == obj.idperson && people[i].nameperson == obj.nameperson ){
             return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="idperson"><input type="text" id="name">
    <button id="add" type="button">ADD</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript objects

```
<script>
var people = {};

$("#add").click(function(){
    var iduser = $("#idperson").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();

    if(!(iduser in people)){
        people[iduser] = name;
    }
    console.log(people);
});
</script>
```